# Word template avoid empty lines if data not given

Tags: freemarker, xdocreport

I'm using XDocReport to generate pdf file from docx word template.
In my template I have following:

```
Name <<${data.name}>> 
<<[#if data.nickname??]>>Nickname <<${data.nickname}>><<[/#if]>>  
Surname <<${data.surname}>>
```

The problem is when there is no nickname, then I have extra empty line between Name and Surname.
Is there a way I can avoid this?
I would like to have nickname displayed between if it is given.
Otherwise I would like to display Name following directly with Surname without the extra line.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please see [Meta: Should questions include tags in their titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is, no, they should not.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `if` tags into their own lines, the horizontal whitespace around them and the linebreak after them is ignored:

```
Name ${data.name}
[#if data.nickname??]
Nickname ${data.nickname}
[/#if]
Surname ${data.surname}
```

Comment: This didn't help, I still have this extra line in between Name and Surname. Do you know something else that could help?

Comment: Then I'm afraid the problem will be that you aren't editing the raw template, but some WYSIWYG document. So a row that looks like `Nickname ${name.nickname}` will be actually something like `<paragraph>Nickname ${name.nickname}</paragraph>` when it gets to FreeMarker, and of course it won't remove those tags, as it's not white-space. I don't know if there's any special syntax for removing the enclosing element in XDocReport.